# How to do Inverse Regex match [regex negation] in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

Is there a way to do inverse `regular expression` match and retrieve the un-matching string as return value in `iOS` `Swift`?

Let's say,

Input string: "`232#$%4lion`"

Regex Pattern: "`[a-z]{4}`"

Normal match Output: "`lion`"

Inverse match output: "`232#$%4`" (Expected result)

Please find the normal regex matching swift code below.

```
func regexMatch() {

    let str = "232#$%4lion"

    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[a-z]{4}", options: .caseInsensitive)
    let firstMatch = regex.firstMatch(in: str, options: .reportProgress, range: NSMakeRange(0, str.count))
    guard let matches = firstMatch else {
        print("No Match")
        return
    }

    if matches.numberOfRanges > 0 {
        let outputRange = matches.range(at: 0)
        let startIndex = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: outputRange.lowerBound)
        let endIndex = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: outputRange.upperBound)
        print("Matched String: \(str[startIndex..<endIndex])")
    }
}
```

I can somehow manipulate the matching result and then, can retrieve the inverse matching string by manipulating range operations. Instead of doing that,
I want to know if inverse matching can be done using regex pattern itself in Swift and directly retrieve un-matching pattern from the input string.

Above input and output values are for reference purpose only. Just to keep the question simple. Actual values in real time cases can be complex. Please answer with a generic solution.

Comment: You could replace the match with an empty string leaving `232#$%4`

Comment: Just replace as the 4th bird suggests: `let result = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "[a-z]{4}", with: "", options: .regularExpression)`

Comment: Thanks @Thefourthbird. It makes sense.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew. Please post your solution as an answer. I can upvote and accept.

Comment: Ok, posted with explanations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use your regex to *remove* (replace with an empty string) the matches found:

```
let result = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "[a-z]{4}", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

Swift test:

```
let str = "232#$%4lion"
let result = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "[a-z]{4}", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
print(result)
```

Output: `232#$%4`.

Answer (score 1):

Either use this pattern, however it doesn't invert `{4}` because it's not predictable

```
"[^a-z]+"
```

or create a new mutable string from `str` and remove the found range

```
func invertedRegexMatch() {

    let str = "232#$%4lion"

    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[a-z]{4}", options: .caseInsensitive)
    let firstMatch = regex.firstMatch(in: str, options: .reportProgress, range: NSRange(str.startIndex..., in: str))
    guard let matches = firstMatch else {
        print("No Match")
        return
    }

    if matches.numberOfRanges > 0 {
        let outputRange = Range(matches.range(at: 0), in: str)!
        var invertedString = str
        invertedString.removeSubrange(outputRange)
        print("Matched String: \(invertedString)")
    }
}
```

Note: Use **always** the dedicated API to create `NSRange` from `Range<String.Index>` and vice versa

But if you just want to remove all letters there is a much simpler way

```
var str = "232#$%4lion"
str.removeAll{$0.isLetter}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use a regular expression for that. You can just use filter. 
`RangeReplaceableCollection` has a [filter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rangereplaceablecollection/2908316-filter) instance method that returns `Self`, `String` conforms to `RangeReplaceableCollection`, so filter when used with a `String` returns another `String`. 
You can combine it with the new `Character` property `isLetter` (Swift5) and create a predicate negating that property.

---

```
let str = "232#$%4lion"
let result = str.filter { !$0.isLetter }
print(result)   // "232#$%4"
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I want to know how to do regex negation in swift. The example text given are just for reference purpose. Anyway, i learned new thing here: "isLetter" in Swift 5. Once again, thanks.